# Agregar Datos a SELECT dinámicos a filas dinámicas (FOREACH)

Tags: javascript, laravel

Bien, primero que todo no se como formular bien la pregunta. en todo caso en lo que necesito ayuda es en:

Tengo un código `javascript` con el cual aumento filas a una tabla, uso `appendClild` para eso, aquí el codigo:

```
var td1 = document.createElement("td");
td1.setAttribute("colspan", "2");
    var div_sel = document.createElement("div");
    div_sel.setAttribute("class", "form-group-custom");

        var seleccion = document.createElement("select");
        seleccion.setAttribute("class", "form-control form-control-sm-custom");
        seleccion.setAttribute("id", "inputState");
            var opcion = document.createElement("option");
            opcion.text = "Seleccionar...";
            opcion.value = "cantidad" //AQUI ES DONDE DEBERIA ESTAR LOS DATOS DEL @FOREACH
        
seleccion.appendChild(opcion);
div_sel.appendChild(seleccion);
td1.appendChild(div_sel);
```

Bien lo que hago es agregar `select` a un `td` que luego sera agregado a un `tr` y así...
este es el ejemplo del resultado con un primer `tr` con los respectivos campos y el foreach de forma correcta.
Código:

```
<td>
   <div class="form-group-custom">
       <select id="inputState" class="form-control form-control-sm-custom">
             <option selected value="0">Seleccionar...</option>
                   @foreach ($sbu_datos as $item)
                         <option value="{{$item->sbu_id}}" title="{{$item->grupo_ocupacional}}">{{$item->abreviatura}}</option>
                   @endforeach
       </select>
   </div>
</td>
```

Imagen:
Como se aprecia si muestra el dato de la BDD con el `@foreach`.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando agrego la primera fila que se crea con `appendChild` se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como cargar son los datos para que se muestren...

Answer (score 2):

*En resumen lo que necesitas es recorrer tu arreglo **sbu_datos**, para crear los option que te faltan en tu select con su respectivo valor. Dejo un ejemplo de como puedes hacerlo*:

```js
var sbu_datos = [
    { sbu_id: 1, abreviatura: 'valor 1' },
    { sbu_id: 2, abreviatura: 'valor 2' },
    { sbu_id: 3, abreviatura: 'valor 3' },
    { sbu_id: 4, abreviatura: 'valor 4' },
    { sbu_id: 5, abreviatura: 'valor 5' },
    { sbu_id: 6, abreviatura: 'valor 6' },
];

var contenedor = document.getElementById('container');

var seleccion = document.createElement('select');
seleccion.setAttribute('class', 'form-control form-control-sm-custom');
seleccion.setAttribute('id', 'inputState');

var opcion = document.createElement('option');
opcion.text = 'Seleccionar...';
opcion.value = '0';
seleccion.appendChild(opcion);

sbu_datos.forEach(item => {
    opcion = document.createElement('option');
    opcion.text = item.abreviatura;
    opcion.value = '' + item.sbu_id;
    seleccion.appendChild(opcion);
});

contenedor.appendChild(seleccion);
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mt-3" id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Considera que aunque interesante la respuesta esperada deberá involucrar AJAX y Laravel de lo contrario me parece queda corta tu solución